# Client side templates and partial views and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, partial-views, templating, express

We have a large amount of client side templating solutions recently including:

- [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)
- [John resig micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)
- [handle bars](http://handlebars.strobeapp.com/)
- [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- and more

As far as I can see only jQuery templates support the concept of partials templates (in this case the `{{tmpl}}`).

What other templating engines allow for partial or nested templates?

I'm not an expert on [express](http://expressjs.com/) and I don't know how the partials work under the hood.

How do you integrate a non-standard templating engine into express ? (The standards are Jade or EJS).

Comment: @MPelletier we also have the `express` tag. I'd personally recommend changing `express.js`/`expressjs` to `express`.

Comment: I was just eliminating `expressjs` by merging it to its closest relative. I'd rather Meta decide on this `express` vs `express.js`, mostly because there are more than I care to retag by hand. I have a bias against `express` mostly because people will use it for any "Express" version of other technologies (C#, SQLServer, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templating engines must provide a `compile` function.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js#L367

You can define the default templating engine by doing `app.set('view engine', 'jqtpl')` or let express guess from the file extension. Express will load automatically that engine by requiring it.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view/view.js#L122

You can see one example using markdown for example:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/markdown/app.js

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Knockout.js. It's an awesome data binding/templating solution that can re-render onscreen HTML *on the fly* by watching your data model.

http://knockoutjs.com/

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08

Supports nested templates (in a few different ways), attaching events to your templates, having compound template variables, and attaching your model objects to both input and output elements.

Way more flexible than the built-in jQuery templating, or other data binding options like Chain.js :)

Comment: Is the knockout templating engine supported by express? Can the views be used on both node.js and the browser? Don't get me wrong, knockout is awesome, it's just I need one templating engine for both server and client.

Comment: I haven't used it with Node yet, but I think it should work as an additional layer inside Express' templating system. Express would handle your basic app framework, pages, and MVC structure. Then build out all your client-side components in Knockout templates (they're just JS inside the html) and connect the Knockout data model to what you've got already. Hope this helps

Comment: to give a more technical answer: Knockout follows the MVVM pattern, which basically inserts a layer (the "View Model") alongside the view, in addition to your existing model/controller, see: http://bit.ly/bdBjEy

Comment: @dylanized the end object is re-using view code on the server for clients with JavaScript disabled. Could I re-use my clientside knockout code out of the box on the server?

Comment: This mapping plugin looks cool too, automaps JSON to a Knockout View Model http://bit.ly/lporbo

Comment: @Raynos I think the Knockout instantiation would work server side, and be used to build out your html, but you'd probably have to run it all again clientside if you wanted to rebuild things dynamically in the browser. I'd love to hear if you can pull this off, dylan@electrolabs.info